# Laravel Sanctum auth:sanctum route allows access without bearer token

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to protect API routes with a bearer token using Laravel Sanctum.

I have added the middleware correctly for the route as follows in api.php. The api/me route is set to return auth()->user();

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post('/me', 'App\Http\Controllers\APIController@me');
});
```

To test this, I first login successfully and generate a bearer token, so that is working fine.

However, when I try to access the api/me route without the bearer token, it still displays the full user. It is not supposed to be allowing access to the route without a bearer token, why is it doing that?

I've searched for hours but no joy - does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 11):

I'm just guessing here.. Did you "EnsureFrontendRequestAreStateful" in kernel.php?
Because then Sanctum will use Session-Cookie based authentication. Sanctum will only use the bearer token if you authenticate third party apps, that don't run on your domain or subdomain.

If you don't want to use session-cookie based authentication for your SPA remove the "EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful" class from kernel.php.
Now Sanctum will always use the bearer token for authentication.

Comment: Hey there yes I did, if that’s the case, how do you test that the bearer authentication is working on localhost dev environment?

Comment: In this case you don't want to ensure that frontend requests are stateful. So remove that class from kernel.php

Comment: @raistie would be nice if you could upvote this answer as it seems to solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to but my reputation is insufficient :(

Comment: @NICO I was wondering if you can be of help to me at all. I have the exact opposite of the problem to the OP. I have the EnsureFrontendRequestAreStateful but yet I can't get sanctum to authenticate my API requests, I have followed the documentation but still no joy. Can I PM you?

Comment: @oluwatyson Sure. I'll be out until late evening but will take a look at it.

Comment: @NICO I am not sure how to PM on here actually but I managed to find your website and tried to email you and it bounced back. Any idea on how I can reach you? Really really appreciate this btw

Comment: @oluwatyson Hey, there shouldn't be any problems with the email address on my website..just tested it. If that doesn't work for whatever reason just send me your email address through the contact form on my website.

Comment: @oluwatyson there seems to be something wrong with your email. ***.co.uk is down.

Comment: Alas the problem was form my end! I've used another email to email you. @NICO

Comment: This answer deserve more up votes. I have seen lots of other questions where people wanted to have stateless authentication using sanctum but could not find the most simple solution!

Comment: Came here looking for a solution to the same issue.  I have tried with and without EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class in my middlewareGroups, but whether it's there or not, auth-sanctum does not protect my route.